# RuleUnit + Quarkus example's drl file - Are we instantiating a new rule `AllAmounts` with this code?

Tags: java, drools, kogito

I do not understand a few parts of this `drl` code, but I'll just post one question here:

https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/stable/ruleunit-quarkus-example/src/main/resources/org/kie/kogito/queries/RuleUnitQuery.drl

The full drl code is here:

```
package org.kie.kogito.queries;
unit LoanUnit;
import org.kie.kogito.queries.LoanApplication;
import org.kie.kogito.queries.AllAmounts;
rule SmallDepositApprove when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit < 1000, amount <= 2000 ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(true) };
end
rule SmallDepositReject when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit < 1000, amount > 2000 ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(false) };
end
rule LargeDepositApprove when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit >= 1000, amount <= maxAmount ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(true) };
end
rule LargeDepositReject when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age >= 20, deposit >= 1000, amount > maxAmount ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(false) };
end
rule NotAdultApplication when
    $l: /loanApplications[ applicant.age < 20 ]
then
    modify($l) { setApproved(false) };
end
query FindApproved
    $l: /loanApplications[ approved ]
end
query FindNotApprovedIdAndAmount
    /loanApplications[ !approved, $id: id, $amount : amount ]
end
rule AllAmounts
when
    accumulate ( $a : /loanApplications ; $sum : sum($a.amount))
then
    allAmounts.add(new AllAmounts($sum));
end
query FindAllApplicationAmounts
    $a : /allAmounts
end
```

In the line of code `allAmounts.add(new AllAmounts($sum));`, are we instantiating a new rule `AllAmounts` with this code?  The rule `AllAmounts` does not seem to take any parameters, so how is `$sum` passed to the rule?

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in your question itself. If in the future that file is moved or changed, it causes your question to no longer be of any use and make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is that you're using the methods provided by the RuleUnit `LoanUnit`, namely the `allAmounts` DataStore:

```
public DataStore<AllAmounts> getAllAmounts()
```

The rule in question is this one:

```
rule AllAmounts
when
    accumulate ( $a : /loanApplications ; $sum : sum($a.amount))
then
    allAmounts.add(new AllAmounts($sum));
end
```

Line-by-line, this is what's happening:

```
rule AllAmounts
when
    accumulate ( 
                 $a : /loanApplications ; // for each loan application ($a)
                 $sum : sum($a.amount)    // sum up the amount; assign output to $sum
                )
then
    allAmounts.add(
                   new AllAmounts($sum) // create a new AllAmounts object
    );                                  // and add it to the AllAmounts datastore (working memory)
end
```

Recall that Drools "finds" properties based on Java Bean naming conventions -- so when you refer to some field in a class, it first checks for the presence of a "getter" for that field. That's what happening here with this confusing syntax: even though we've never declared a *variable* called `allAmounts`, we *do* have a getter in the RuleUnit called `getAllAmounts` ... that's what we're getting.

A DataStore is one of the ways Kogito makes information available to its rules. In the [Kogito documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/kogito/release/latest/html_single/#_data_sources_for_drl_rule_units), it's defined like this:

> **DataStore:** A writable storage option for adding or removing data and then notifying all subscribers that mutable data has been modified. Rules can pattern-match against incoming values and update or remove available values. For users familiar with Drools, this option is equivalent to a typed version of an entry point. In fact, a `DataStore<Object>` is equivalent to an old-style entry point.

Note that Drools also has a *`DataSource`* interface that's quite similar; you can just about think of them the same way. Both are *basically* wrappers around the collection of objects of a particular type in working memory. So what this rule effectively does is it creates a new `AllAmounts` object, then adds to to the DataStore representing the data in working memory.

At no point are we executing a rule "by name" -- that was an unfortunate naming choice on the part of the example writers. Rules aren't executed on demand like this, they're executed in a series based on fact matches the conditional clause.

---

#### References

- You can read more about RuleUnits in the Drools documentation [here](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rule-units-con_decision-engine).
- Drools DataSources are also discussed in the Drools documentation [here](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#_data_sources_for_rule_units).
- The `/loanApplication` syntax is OOPath notation, which doesn't appear to have dedicated documentation anywhere, but there's example with it in the Drools docs as well.
- I am unable to find the Javadoc for the Kogito DataStore, but they're discussed in the Kogito documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/kogito/release/latest/html_single/#_data_sources_for_drl_rule_units).

Comment: Thanks!  I've a new question which you may be able to answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907877/ruleunit-quarkus-examples-missing-java-file-that-should-contain-kieservices-a