# RuleUnit + Quarkus example's missing Java file that should contain KieServices and KieContainer - how does it work without these items?

Tags: java, drools, kogito

I've a question based on an external archive:

https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/stable/ruleunit-quarkus-example

I read from:

https://docs.drools.org/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#kie-sessions-stateless-con_decision-engine

"
In this example, the sample rule and all other files in the ~/resources folder of the Drools project are built with the following code:

Create the KIE container

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
```

"

However, for the archive of `ruleunit-quarkus-example`, I've git cloned the archive and grep searched the files:

```
grep -r "KieServices" ./*
grep -r "KieContainer" ./*
```

But could not find any file with `KieServices` and `KieContainer` inside.  But `ruleunit-quarkus-example` executes without problems.  How does it work without `KieServices` and `KieContainer`?  And does this create stateless or stateful sessions?

Comment: Pretty sure you're getting it from one of the dozen dependencies that project has on a variety of kogito/quarkus libraries, probably in the same place as (or near to) where it spins up and exposes a REST interface for the rules. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with those libraries, since I do old-fashioned (pure) Drools.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, thanks, i've git cloned the whole archive at https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples and grep through all files and folders and found nothing.  it's truly a mystery for a newbie like me...

Comment: You picked an opinionated framework, it's going to do a lot of stuff for you. I would recommend reading over the Kogito docs -- good, mature opinionated frameworks (eg. Spring) document their opinions well and also explain how to override the configuration. But like most frameworks, part of their draw is that you don't _need_ to know where it's hiding the nuts and bolts.

Comment: Hi, @maxloo, the main issue is that you are trying Kogito, but you are reading the docs for Drools v7. Kogito is based on Drools but it currently ships with a few extensions. The RuleUnit API existed in v7, but it was experimental; it was overhauled for Kogito and it's pretty different. Refer to the Kogito docs to learn more https://kogito.kie.org/guides/  

source: I am a Kogito developer :-)

Comment: Yep. The Drools docs are great if you want to learn about the underlying rules and rule framework in general, but for the extra special sauce that kogito applies on top you really do need to read the kogito docs.

Comment: @EdoardoVacchi, Thanks, I've posted my amended question at https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232676-kogito/topic/ruleunit-quarkus-example.20-.20How.20to.20save.20the.20data.20we.20posted.3F.  I've also added 2 more questions: one about DMN and one about SCESIM.

Comment: you're welcome @maxloo I'll reply again with an "answer" so you can mark this as solved

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are trying Kogito, but you are reading the docs for Drools v7.

Kogito is based on Drools but it currently ships with a few extensions. The RuleUnit API existed in v7, but it was experimental; it was overhauled for Kogito and it's pretty different.

Refer to the Kogito docs to learn more kogito.kie.org/guides

source: I am a Kogito developer :-)